# How do I take data from one observation and apply it to one other observation within a group?

Tags: stata

An unmarried couple is living together in a house with other people. To isolate how much that couple makes I need to add the two incomes together. I am using variables that act as pointers that give the `partners_id`. Using the `partners_id`, `id` , and `individual_income` how do I apply partner's income to his/her partner?

This was my attempt below:

```
summarize id, meanonly
capture gen partners_income = 0

forvalue ln = 1/`r(max)' {
    bys household (id): ///
    egen link_`ln' = total(individual_income) if partners_location==`ln')
    replace partners_income = link_`ln' if link_`ln' > 0 & id == `ln'
    drop link_*
}
```

Comment: My apologies for the multiple edits. I am still getting used to this forum.

Comment: Don't apologise - editing a Q or A to make it better is what this site is all about. When you've got enough rep, you can do it to other users posts too. In any case, welcome to SO, hope you find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is general advice in [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-variables-recording-properties/).

It can take longer to write a smart way to do this than to use a quick-and-dirty approach.

However, there is a smarter way.

**Brute solution**

Quick here means relatively quick to code; this isn't guaranteed quick for a very large dataset.

```
gen partners_income = . 
gen problem = 0
```

The proper initialisation of the partner's income variable is to missing, not zero. Not knowing an income and the income being zero are different conditions. For example, if someone doesn't have a partner, the income will certainly be missing. (If at a later stage, you want to treat missings as zeros, that's up to you, but you should keep them distinct at this stage.)

The reason for the `problem` variable will become apparent.

I can't see a reason for your `capture`.

Now we can loop:

```
quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
      su individual_income if id == partners_id[`i'], meanonly 
      replace partners_income = r(max) in `i' 
      if r(N) > 1 replace problem = r(N) in `i' 
}
```

So, the logic is

`foreach` observation

1. find the partner's identifier
2. find that income: `summarize, meanonly` is fast
3. that should be **one** value, so it should be immaterial whether we pick it up from the results of `summarize` as the maximum, minimum, or mean
4. but if `summarize` finds more than one value, something is not as assumed (mistakes over identifiers, or multiple partners); later we `edit if problem` and look at those observations.

Notes:

We can make comparison safer by restricting computations to the same household by modifying

```
if id == partners_id[`i']
```

to

```
if id == partners_id[`i'] & household == household[`i']
```

In one place you have the variable `partners_location` which looks like a typo for `partners_id`.

**Cute solution**

Assuming that partners name each other as partner (and this is not the forum to explore exceptions), then couples have a joint identity which we obtain by sorting "John Joanna" and "Joanna John" to "Joanna John" or the equivalent with numeric identifiers:

```
gen first = cond(id < partner_id, id, partner_id) 
gen second = cond(id < partner_id, partner_id, id) 
egen joint = concat(first second), p(" ")
```

`first` and `second` just mean in numeric or alphanumeric order; this works for numeric and string identifiers. You may need to slap on an exclusion clause such as

```
if !missing(partner_id)
```

Now

```
bysort household joint : gen partners_income = income[3 - _n] if _N == 2
```

Get it? Each distinct combination of `household` and `joint` should be precisely 2 observations for us to be interested (hence the qualifier `if _N == 2`). If that's true then `3 - _n` gives us the subscript of the *other* partner as if `_n` is 1 then `3 - _n` is 2 and vice versa. Under `by:` subscripts are always applied within groups, so that `_n` runs 1, 2, and so forth in each distinct group.

If this seems cryptic, it is all spelled out in [Cox, N.J. 2008. The problem of split identity, or how to group dyads. *Stata Journal* 8(4): 588-591](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043) which is accessible as a .pdf.

Comment: Yes, I believe I understand how both solutions work. I hadn't used the concatenate function before so I had to look that up. I only started learning how to use macros, loops, etc in the last month in order to complete my research analysis, so much of this is new to me. Thank you for your most generous help.

Comment: @user3274019 You can accept the answer if you like it. You would gain a little reputation thereby.